# Is the power frequency characteristic of a network almost constant?

Tags: frequency, stability, transient, power-grid

When a transient phenomenon happens in an electric power grid, the network reacts to this deviation with a power-frequency characteristic (MW/Hz). Reading the following paper ''Analysis and Simulations of the Primary Frequency Control during a System Split in Continental Europe Power System, Mariano G. Ippolito, Rossano Musca * and Gaetano Zizzo'' I saw that the equivalent model of the network to represent the event described (a system split) uses a constant power frequency characteristic.

But can the power frequency characteristic of a network be considered almost constant during an event whatever frequency is reached?

Because I have a doubt regarding this. For example, one contribution of the power frequency characteristic is given from the primary reserves which are activated within a deviation of 200 mHz and give a maximum contribution of 3 GW (almost), therefore gives a contribution of 3 GW/200 mHz = 15000 MW/Hz to the power frequency characteristic. Therefore when frequency overcomes the range of 200 mHz this contribution is no more present and the power frequency characteristic should change.

Comment: Imagine that the powerline frequency is 99999999999999Hz. All generators slam on the brakes. Can more than 100% of generators slam on the brakes? No, there is a maximum stopping force. Now imagine that the powerline frequency is 0.000001Hz and all generators are running at maximum capacity. Obviously at this extreme there is also zero power-frequency characteristic. Yet somewhere in the middle it is not zero. Therefore it is not a constant.

Comment: @user253751 :( your answer is correct but obvious... Under 47.5 Hz and 51.5 Hz (in CE) there is a collapse... I mean if it is constant in the range 47.5-51.5 Hz... :(